# Cannot access localhost with dockerized app

Tags: docker, deno

MacOS Monterey

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM denoland/deno:1.29.1

EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN deno cache ./src/index.ts

CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "--allow-read", "./src/index.ts"]
```

And the most simple deno code

```
const handler = (request: Request) => {
  return new Response("heyo", { status: 200 });
};
DenoServer.serve(handler, { hostname: HOST, port: PORT });
```

Running the application locally works fine and I can reach `localhost:4200`. However when I run the app with docker the request fails

I use

```
docker run --publish 4200:4200 frontend
```

```
└───> curl http://localhost:4200                                                                    
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I can see the container running and trying to hit the `{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}` doesn't work either

[docker container running on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGKzL.png)

Comment: Update: This may be an issue with Deno specifically. I can do nearly identical setup with a simple Go server and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the necessary environment variables were not included in the docker run command. To specify the host and port, you can use the -e option in the docker command.

```
docker build -t deno-sample .
docker run -e HOST=localhost -e PORT=4200 -p 4200:4200 deno-sample
```

For more information, please refer to the Docker documentation at the following link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

```
FROM denoland/deno:1.29.1

EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

# RUN deno cache ./src/index.ts
RUN ls

CMD ["deno", "run", "--allow-net", "--allow-read", "app.ts"]
```

Here is my app.ts in same path as of dockerfile

```
function requestHandler() {
  console.log(">>>>>")
  return new Response("Hey, I'm a server")
}

serve(requestHandler, { hostname: '0.0.0.0', port: 4200 })
```

Comment: Are host and port required? Ive used the `run` command in the past without them with no issues. In either case, providing these args does not work. I added a comment where I think this has to do with Deno and maybe not Docker itself

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'll try this out - I ended up going back to node because deno wasn't worth the headaches